# How can I add to the "Error Log" section in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, error-log

[image]

I am trying to make an Eclipse plugin that enables a student with no knowledge of English to code. So I want to take the errors of what he coded [in his own language], translate them and put them in the Error Log for him to see and understand.

How can I write in the "Error Log"?

Comment: *"enables a student with no knowledge of English to code"*  That is a tough task, given all the Java SE class names and keywords are in English.

Comment: yes It is .. what I can't do now is writing in the Error Log .. Any help ?

Comment: I don't (often) use Eclipse (just English).  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear of the use case here. But based on partial understanding, here is what you can do. You can wrap each exception/error with your exception hierarchy with language/locale of your choice and then print out wrapped error/exception into it. Keep this log file in the project path, so it will be accessible from within. Parse it and display it as and when it gets updated. So instead of checking the error log panel, you can see your log file for the reference.