# Capturing eclipse error log

Tags: eclipse, error-logging, error-log

I'm looking to capture-- write to a file the contents of `Error Log` in Eclipse. How is this done? It's the `Error Log` shown in the screen-shot in this [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354549/how-can-i-add-to-the-error-log-section-in-eclipse).

Note: I've seen [Eclipse PDE Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122787/eclipse-pde-logging) and [How can I add to the "Error Log" section in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354549/how-can-i-add-to-the-error-log-section-in-eclipse) among some other discussions.

TIA.

Comment: The error log is already in a file - the '.log' file in the workspace '.metadata' directory.

Comment: @greg-449 this makes it - thx